# HTML Table BorderColor differs dramatically between browsers

Tags: html, css, html-table, cross-browser

I have a bit of an annoying issue whereby my tables seem to be appearing completely differently between browsers, they are set as:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="4"  cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#eeeeee">
```

So the left one (Chrome) is correct at #eeeeee, but FF and IE just seem to be making it up as they go along!!
There is nothing in my CSS that is event vaguely close to specifying a table border (I even tried un-linking my CSS files and the issue remained)

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Side note: If you aren't already, do a hard refresh of the webpage when making changes to CSS etc as it is likely that the changes you make won't always be reflected e.g. if the files are cached by the browser. `CTRL + F5` forces browser to re-download all associated files.

Comment: Note that `bordercolor` was dropped in atleast HTML4 and moved to CSS. And you can move all of those attributes to CSS these days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ### @Darkat Studios
>
> `<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px solid  #eeeeee;">` - now there IS indeed a light grey border, HOWEVER the cells are all still black outlined.. VERY odd! –

you should remove the border="1"

Comment: @DarkcatStudios I gave you the same answer. Crazy people!

Answer (score 4):

Try this CSS

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 100%;
}
table th,
table td
{
    padding: 4px;
}
```

And change your HTML to simply state

```html
<table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give that in CSS:

```
table {border: 2px solid #eeeeee;}
```

Or at least:

```
table {border-style: solid;}
```

Now check in all the browsers.

Comment: Thanks, but oddly even that didnt help (although it did colour another table on the page THE CORRECT colour!!)

Comment: <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="4"  cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px solid #eeeeee;"> - now there IS indeed a light grey border, HOWEVER the cells are all still black outlined.. VERY odd!

Comment: and its now actually worse in chrome! which now lookes like it does in FF

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the implementation of the nonstandard attribute `bordercolor` varies across browsers. It even depends on browser mode (Standards vs. Quirks mode).

You can make the situation more consistent by setting, in CSS, all border properties on the `table` element *and* its cells. Or you could style the table and its cells in CSS only.

Comment: That makes sense yes - the reason I was unaware that bordercolor was deprecated was 2-fold: 1: I dont read through w3c very often (ever!) and 2: 99.9% of the tables ive put into websites over the last 15 years have been invisible anyway!

Answer (score -3):

Try remove the '#' bordercolor="eeeeee"